# In Typescript how do I allow a type to have all keys of a generic that point to a recursive value of that type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Right now I have something like this where "any" can act as the generic "V"

```
interface Validation<V> {
  $isValid: boolean
  $isValidating: boolean
  $value: V
  [prop: string]: boolean | V | Validation<V>
}
```

What I'd like to do is replace the string indexing type with any string key K from V will return a sub Validation interface.

```
interface Validation<V> {
  $isValid: boolean
  $isValidating: boolean
  $value: V
  [K extends Extract<keyof V, string>]: Validation<V[K]>
}
```

This clearly doesn't work and curious to know if something similar is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here is how to do it

```
type Validation<V> = {
    [K in Extract<keyof V, string>]: Validation<V[K]>
} & {
    $isValid: boolean
    $isValidating: boolean
    $value: V
}
```

1. You should use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), so you should write `K in ...`.

   > The syntax resembles the syntax for index signatures with a `for .. in` inside. There are three parts:
   >
   > - The type variable K, which gets bound to each property in turn.
   > - The string literal union Keys, which contains the names of properties to iterate over.
   > - The resulting type of the property.
2. To dd additional properties use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), as it is not possible to add additional properties to mapped type directly.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you @Fyodor